# 'drag' move a uibutton so it acts like uiScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, drag, swipe

I need to slide a uibutton up and down the screen (Y only). It needs to be confined to an area. I want to be able to click on it and drag **or** flick it, just like a uiScrollView. The reason it is different to a uiScrollView is that you have to start on the button, as opposed to anywhere inside a uiScrollView!

Answer (score 4):

You can move a view by using touch moved event. There is a sample tutorial [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple  which drags a view and after releasing the touch animate the view. Check specially the touch events (touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded) in [MoveMeView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Listings/Classes_MoveMeView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007315-Classes_MoveMeView_m-DontLinkElementID_6) to get the idea how they have moved placardView. You can move your button just like the placardView.

Comment: Many thanks, I will have a good look after work! I wonder though (just looking at the description) if I will need to know the direction (like with a swipe) to animate in that direction? This tutorial returns the object back to the centre.

Comment: I am afraid that in that case you need to calculate the direction from the touch locations yourself.

Comment: Its a shame I can't have exactly what uiScrollView does but on a uiButton or uiLabel.. could there be a bool available on uiScrollView to 'allow' scroll? maybe I could then put that on my uiButton and add the uiButton to the uiScrollView? hmmm