# Move a button in the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an `UIButton` and I want to move that button by touching and swiping it in the screen. When I release the touch it will be in the current position. Explain clearly, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can move a view by using touch moved event. There is a sample tutorial [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple  which drags a view and after releasing the touch animate the view. Check specially the touch events (touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded) in [MoveMeView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Listings/Classes_MoveMeView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007315-Classes_MoveMeView_m-DontLinkElementID_6) to get the idea how they have moved placardView. You can move your button just like the placardView.

Taken from ['drag' move a uibutton so it acts like uiScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863539/drag-move-a-uibutton-so-it-acts-like-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 2):

check [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/)

you should make move frame from the points and move frame accordingly so that your button moves in places of touches

Answer (score 1):

If you are scripting for iOS 3.2 and above, consider using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Simply attach an instance of it like this,

```
...
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;

[self.button addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];
...
```

and define `handlePan:` like this,

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture {
    CGRect buttonFrame = self.button.frame;
    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:panGesture.view];

    buttonFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
    buttonFrame.origin.y += translation.y;

    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:panGesture.view];
    self.button.frame = buttonFrame;
}
```