# Drag button with touch move

Tags: iphone, ios, button, drag

I am working on a custom controller. I want to create a slider, to choose between more options. The problem is that when I touch the button I want to it doesn't call my `touchesBegan` method. But if I press in any other part of my view, it works. How can I get my button to move?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The UIButton is capturing the touch events. if you try this

```
myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Then it will no longer consume the touch events but it will also no longer fire the onTouchUpInside event.  In this case you process all of the touches in the super view and position the slider button accordingly.

It should drag just fine. This will work for any UIView.

Answer (score 0):

touchesBegan will not work on a UIButton .. for that to work you will have to subclass UIButton and implement touchesBegan

refer this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863734/919545

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom UIView and avoid using the UIButton class? It is simplier that subclassing UIButto or to set

```
myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I will do in the end. I wanted to add a touch up effect when I press on the slider.

Comment: You'll see that this is the best choice. In very few time you can create every touch effect that you want